# you must provide at least one recipient email address

Tags: php, frontend, email, phpmailer

Пытаюсь организовать отправку сообщения на почту через php mailer. Ошибка на скрине:[[image: Ошибка, при этом появляется всплывающее окно где написано что сообщение отправлено[1]

**Код phpmailer**

```
                <?php
            // start session
            session_start();
            if(!isset($_SESSION["state"])){
                $_SESSION["state"] = true;
            }
            //autoload classes
            require 'pm/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
            //Create a new PHPMailer instance
            $mail = new PHPMailer;

            function mail_send($from_mail, $from_name, $to_mail, $to_name, $subject, $msg){
                global $mail;
                //Set who the message is to be sent from
                $mail->setFrom($from_mail, $from_name);

                //Set an alternative reply-to address
                $mail->addReplyTo($from_mail, $from_name);

                //Set who the message is to be sent to
                $mail->addAddress($to_mail, $to_name);

                $mail->isHTML(true);

                //Set the subject line
                $mail->Subject = $subject;

                //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
                $mail->msgHTML($msg);

                //send the message, check for errors
                if (!$mail->send()) {
                    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {
                    echo"<script>alert('Сообщение отправлено!'); location.href='index.html'</script>";
                    exit;
                }
            }
            if(isset($_POST['send_mail'])){

                unset($_SESSION["state"]);
                $wish_sub = "Merry Christmas From ". $_SESSION["urname"];
                mail_send($_SESSION["email"], $_SESSION["urname"], $_SESSION["friends_email"], $_SESSION["frndsname"],$wish_sub, $_SESSION["html"] );
            }
            else if($_POST["msg_btn"]){
                unset($_SESSION["state"]);
                $msg_name = $_POST['msg_name'];
                $msg_email = $_POST['msg_email'];
                $msg_phone = $_POST["msg_phone"];
                $msg_message = $_POST["msg_messgae"];
                $receiver_mail = "info@domprazdnikov.com";
                $msg_subject = "Email from " . $msg_name;
                mail_send($from_mail, $from_name, $to_mail, $to_name, $subject, $msg);
                mail_send($msg_email, $msg_name, $receiver_mail, $msg_email, $msg_subject, $msg_message);
            }
            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="ru">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">

                <!-- viewport meta -->
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

                <title>Christmas</title>

                <!-- owl carousel css -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css"/>

                <!-- font icofont -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icofont.css"/>

                <!-- Fonts -->
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

                <!-- bootstrap -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

                <!-- animte css -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css"/>

                <!-- style css -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

                <!-- responsive css -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">

                <!-- Favicon -->
                <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/fevicon.png"/>

            </head>
            <body>
                <section class="header_area" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; margin-bottom: 80px;">

                    <!-- NAV AREA CSS -->
                    <div class="nav_area">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">

                                    <!-- MENU AREA STARTS HERE -->
                                    <div class="menu_area">
                                        <div class="logo_container">
                                            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo Image"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- MENU AREA STARTS HERE -->

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- NAV AREA -->

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
                                <h3 style="font-weight: 700; margin-bottom: 40px">Hear Is the preview of You Mail Click.<br>
                                click send button send to the desired recipient</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <?php
                // this test php mailer
            /**
             * This example shows sending a message using PHP's mail() function.
             */


            // make directory uri
            $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $folder = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            array_pop($folder);
            $folder = implode("/", $folder);
            $directory_URI = "http://" . $domain . $folder;

            // file validate message
            $riderect_script = "<script> alert('Sorry fill required fields.'); location.href='send_wishes.html'</script>";
            // check and validate data
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                //check for all the required value
                if($_SESSION["state"]){
                    foreach( $_POST as $x){
                        if($x == ''){
                            echo $riderect_script;
                        }
                    }
                    $_SESSION["state"] = false;
                }


                // Get contents from page
                $_SESSION["email"] = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
                $_SESSION["friends_email"] = isset( $_POST['frineds_email']) ? $_POST['frineds_email'] : false;
                $_SESSION["message"] = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : false;
                $_SESSION["urname"] = isset($_POST['urname']) ? $_POST['urname'] : false;
                $_SESSION["frndsname"] = isset($_POST['frndsname']) ? $_POST['frndsname'] : false;


                if( !$_SESSION["email"] || !$_SESSION["friends_email"] || !$_SESSION["message"] || !$_SESSION["urname"] || !$_SESSION["frndsname"]){
                    echo $riderect_script;
                }
                else{
                    $_SESSION["html"] = <<<"MKUP"
                    <div style="width: 800px; background-image: url('$directory_URI/images/greeting_email_bg.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; margin: 0 auto; height: 820px;">

                    <div style="width: 460px; margin-left: 243px; padding-top: 350px; height: 740px; box-sizing: border-box">
                    <p id="to" style="color: #3c424f; font-family:'Open Sans',Calibri,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 20px; line-height: 48px">To <span style="color: #c93232">$_SESSION[frndsname]</span> ,</p>
                    <p id="message" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Calibri,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:24px; color:#3c424f">
                    $_SESSION[message]
                    </p>
                    <p id="from" style="color: #3c424f; float: right; font-family:'Open Sans',Calibri,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 20px; line-height: 48px">From <span style="color: #c93232">$_SESSION[urname]</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="logo" style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; padding-right: 20px; box-sizing: border-box"><img style="width: 190px; float: right;" src="$directory_URI/images/logo.png"></div>
                    </div>
                    MKUP;
                    echo $_SESSION["html"];
                }

            }
            else{
                echo $riderect_script;
            }
            ?>
            <section style="text-align: center; margin-top: 40px">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <form  method="post">
                                <a class="chris_btn" style="margin-right: 10px" href="send_wishes.html">Cancel!</a>
                                <input class="chris_btn" type="submit" name="send_mail" value="send Mail">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <footer style="margin-top: 80px">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="social_icons">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="icofont icofont-social-facebook"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="icofont icofont-social-twitter"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="icofont icofont-social-behance"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="icofont icofont-social-pinterest"></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="christmas_footer_logo">
                            <img src="images/footer_logo.png" alt="Foogter logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="legal_text">
                            <p> Copyright (c) 2016 Copyright <a href="https://themeforest.net/user/themeebit/portfolio">ThemeeBiT</a> All Rights Reserved. </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Вы должны перевести как минимум одну строчку ошибки :)